# Forwarding traffic to SSLSplit from Android

Tags: man-in-the-middle, android, proxy, iptables

I want to forward non HTTP traffic to SSLSplit in order to do a MITM attack. How would I forward the traffic to SSLSplit from my Android?

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with the following Android proxifiers:

1. [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en)
2. [Postern](http://tunnel-workshop.com/home-en.html)

ProxyDroid has one draw-back; your phone must be rooted. To the best of my knowledge Postern will work on an un-rooted phone.